# Out of a sample of 100 demands what else was asked for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some work on an inbound call demand capture system where each call could have one or more than one demands linked to it.

There is a CaptureHeader table with CallDate, CallReference and CaptureID and a CaptureDemand table with CaptureID and DemandID.

**EDIT:**
I have added some representative data to show what would be expected in each table.

CaptureHeader

```
CaptureID | CallReference | CallDate
-----------------------------------------------
1         | 1             | 2009-11-02 20:37:00
2         | 3             | 2009-11-02 20:37:05
3         | 2             | 2009-11-02 20:37:10
4         | 4             | 2009-11-02 20:38:00
5         | 5             | 2009-11-02 20:38:30
```

CaptureDemand

```
DemandID | CaptureID | DemandText
------------------------------------
1        | 1         | Fund value
2        | 2         | Password reset
3        | 2         | Fund value
4        | 3         | Change address
5        | 3         | Fund value
6        | 3         | Rate change
7        | 3         | Fund value
8        | 4         | Variable to fixed
9        | 4         | Change address
10       | 5         | Fund value
11       | 5         | Address change
```

Using the tables above a filter on 'Fund value' would bring back call references of 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 because 3 has two fund values.

If I did a DISTINCT on this because I have ordered by date it would ask me to show that which would also give me two lines for 3.

To get the full set of data I would do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM CaptureHeader AS ch
JOIN CaptureDemand AS cd ON ch.CaptureID = cd.CaptureID
JOIN DemandDetails AS dd ON cd.DemandID = dd.DemandID
```

What I would like though is to get the last 100 headers by date for a particular demand. Where it gets tricky is when there is more than one of the same demand on a header for a particular reference which is possible.

I would like 100 unique call references because I then need to get back all the demands for those call references and then count how many of each other demand was also recorded in the same call.

**EDIT:**
I would like to be able to say 'WHERE DemandID = SomeValue' to select my 100 references.

In other words out of 100 "value requested" demands what else was asked for. If this doesn't make sense let me know and I will try and modify the question to be clearer.

I would like to get a table like this:

```
Demands          | Count
------------------------
Demand asked for | 100
Another demand   |  36
Third demand     |  12
Fourth demand    |   6
```

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: maybe some sample data would help? I can't quite follow you.
It sounds like Captures and Demands are M:N - but that you are allowing Capture - Demand id pairs to repeat in the join table. Would it be easier if there was a 'count' column in the join table to indicate how many times that relationship occurred for a particular match up?

Comment: The statement "What I would like though is to get the last 100 headers by date for a particular demand" does not match the sample output table you gave.

Comment: I was looking at it in two parts. The first part I was trying to just get 100 call references from the header table for my sample set. I would then use the capture ID of those references to look up the demands in the CaptureDemand table. I am then sorting that data by occurence count descending. In an ideal world there would be 100 of the demand I asked for then less of the others but potentially not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the sample data made your requirement more explicit, I believe the following will generally server your needs.  It is essentially the same as previous submission, with an added condition on the JOIN; this condition essentially excludes any CaptureDemand row for which we readily have the same DemandText (within the same Capture), only retaining the one with the lowest DemandId.

```
WITH myCTE (CaptId, NbOfDemands)
AS (
  SELECT CaptureID, COUNT(*)  -- Can use COUNT(DISTINCT DemandText)
  FROM CaptureDemand
  WHERE CaptureID IN 
    (SELECT TOP 100 C.CaptureID 
     FROM CaptureHeader C
     JOIN CaptureDemand D ON C.CaptureID = D.CaptureID
        AND NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT * FROM CaptureDemand X
           WHERE X.CaptureId = D.CaptureId AND X.DemandText = D.DemandText
              AND X.DemandId < D.DemandId
        )
     WHERE D.DemandText= 'Fund Value'
     ORDER BY CallDate DESC)
)

SELECT NbOfDemands, COUNT(*)
FROM myCTE
GROUP BY NbOfDemands
ORDER BY NbOfDemands
```

What this query provides:
The number of Captures which had exactly one demand
The number of Captures  which had exactly two demands
..
The number of Captures  which had exactly n demands

For the 100 MOST RECENT Captures which included a Demand of a particular value 'someValue' (and, this time, giving indeed 100, i.e. not counting the same CaptureID twice in case of dups on the Demand Type).

A few points:

- You may want to use COUNT(DISTINCT DemandText) rather than COUNT(*) in the select list of the CTE.  (We do include 100 distinct CaptureIDs, i.e. that the Capture #3 in your sample doesn't come twice and hence hiding another capture at the end of the list, but we need to know if this #3 Capture should be counted as 3 Demands or a 4 Demands capture).
- Oops, not quite what you required because each line show the number of Capture instances that have *exactly* this amount of demands...
- use a CASE on NbOfDemands to display the text as in the question (trivial)
- This may show Capture instances with more than 4 demands, but that's probably a plus (if any), but that is probably a plus
- This would not show 0 if for example there were no Capture instances with the given number of demands.

Comment: Thanks @mjv for your solution. I would however be required to say 'WHERE DemandID = SomeValue' in the 'SELECT TOP 100 CaptureID FROM CaptureHeader ORDER BY Time_of_Capture DESC' and because I could have a call with more than 1 of the same demand I wouldn't end up with 100 unique references. I tried using DISTINCT but I was required to put the DateTime in which I didn't want.

Comment: I will amend the question with this point - I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: @Ian See my edit.  I think this would work, unless I missed some subtle (or not so subtle ;-) ) point of the requirement.

Comment: @mjv I was hoping for 100 unique references rather than 100 CaptureIDs. The reason for this is because a call might have more than one of the same demand but I would like that to be one call reference still.

Comment: @Ian, sorry I fail to understand what you mean with 'unique references'.  Maybe this is because there may be more than one row in CaptureHeader for a given  CallReference value ?

Comment: @mjv A call reference is a unique reference for all the demands captured in one call. It's like a grouping reference. One call reference can have multiple capture IDs and demand IDs. The problem I have is if I look for 100 capture IDs of a particular demand ID and a call reference has two of the same demand ID that I am looking for the call reference will appear more than once. Does that make sense?

Comment: So yo still want to the most recent captureIds (possibly filtered by a given criteria) BUT exclude the CaptureIDs that already "came with" the same CallReference?
  BTW, MikeB said it an hour ago, this is probably a case where showing a simplified but representative data example would help understanding the requirement.

Comment: @mjv Check back in ten minutes I'll add one to the original question. Cheers!

Comment: @Ian: see my latest edit.  Essentially added a WHERE NOT EXIST onto the JOIN condition.  Also may want to use COUNT(DISTINCT DemandText) depending on your requirement (=depending whether the Capture IDed #3 needs to be counted as a 3-demands or a 4 demands case)

Comment: Thanks for your help mate this pretty much covers what I need with a few tweaks. You have also taught me how useful CTEs are so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to solve a **Many to Many** problem with just two tables and you really need three tables. For example:

TABLE Calls

```
CallId | CallDate
----------------------------
1      | 2009-11-02 20:37:00
2      | 2009-11-02 20:37:05
3      | 2009-11-02 20:37:10
4      | 2009-11-02 20:38:00
5      | 2009-11-02 20:38:30
```

TABLE Requests

```
RequestId | RequestType
----------------------------
1         | Fund value
2         | Password reset
3         | Change address
4         | Rate change
5         | Variable to fixed
```

TABLE CallRequests (resolves the many to many)

```
CallId |RequestId
-----------------
1      |1        
2      |2      
2      |1      
3      |3      
3      |1      
3      |4
3      |1
4      |5
4      |3
5      |1
5      |3
```

This data structure will let you query from the Call side of things and from the Request side of things.